# Approximation of the following mathematical formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following mathematical expression which I need to simplify:

$$\mu^2\sum_{x=0}^{n}\left(\frac{\theta}{\mu}\right)^x\frac{1}{H_x}{n+a\choose x}$$

$\mu$, $\theta$, $D$, and $a$ are constants.

What is approximation for the mathematical expression?

Regards

Comment: The $n$ inside the summation is $x$. It is not $n$ over which summation is performed.
Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Absolutely. It is correct.

Comment: I know that without the Harmonic Number, the formula is the same as binomial series. So, the main problem is as to how to encounter the Harmonic Number.

Comment: Any hints on relative values? Are they small, large, any? There is little hope for a closed form, best you can get is an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: $n$ is large compared to $a$.

Comment: It's rather sensless to include the constant $\mu^2$ in the question, don't you think? Same for $\theta/ \mu$, which should be a constant. I'd propose to rewrite all as $$\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{b^j}{H_j} {m \choose j}$$

Comment: @SyedTamoor-ul-Hassan, if (in lembloy's formulation) $m \approx n$, it might make sense to go all the way, i e., sum up to $m$. Again, is $b$ large or small?

Comment: @SyedTamoor-ul-Hassan, please edit the question in view of the above comments. Your notation got out of sync.